# Change SQL to Criteria or HQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

Change this query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Authors 
WHERE 
    born <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), interval -55 year)
```

to Criteria query.
This is my bad try

```
 List<Book> bookList = session.createQuery("from Book where born <= DATE_SUB(current_date , INTERVAL 10 year)").list();
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace as well as some more information about the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Spring sends requests as json objects and then tries to convert them to the model that you passed in. In this case it is "Author" which defines born as a Date, but the string that is being sent isn't in the proper date format to be converted to Date.

There are two different ways that you can handle this.

1) Create a Author POJO that defines date as a String and then do your conversion to Author entity manually while specifying the date format

2) Create a Date desearlizer class that will take the string and desearlize it into a date for the specified field:

This is using the jackson library:

```
public class DateTimeStampDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

  private static final String DEFAULT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
  private static final String EXPANDED = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
  private static final String EXPANDED_WITH_TIMEZONE = "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
  private static final String EXPANDED_WITH_AM_PM = "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a";

  private static final String FORMAT_1 = "yyyy-dd-MM";
  private static final String FORMAT_2 = "yyyy/dd/MM";
  private static final String FORMAT_3 = "yyyy.dd.MM";
  private static final String FORMAT_4 = "yyyyddMM";

  private static final String[] formats = new String[] {
      DEFAULT,
      EXPANDED,
      EXPANDED_WITH_TIMEZONE, 
      EXPANDED_WITH_AM_PM,
      FORMAT_1,
      FORMAT_2,
      FORMAT_3,
      FORMAT_4
  };

  private static final Integer[] styles = new Integer[] {
      SimpleDateFormat.LONG,
      SimpleDateFormat.FULL,
      SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM,
      SimpleDateFormat.SHORT
  };

  @Override
  public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String value = p.getText();

    Date date = null;
    //First try to see if the value can be parsed into a long
    try {
      date = new Date(Long.parseLong(value));
      return date;
    } catch (Exception ex) { }

    //Next iterate over the built in styles to see if it can be converted
    for (Integer style: styles) {
      date = formatDate(style, value);
      if (date != null) {
        return date;
      }
    }

    //Lastly iterate over the custom styles specified in format to see if it can be converted
    for (String fmt : formats) {
      date = formatDate(fmt, value);
      if (date != null) {
        return date;
      }
    }

    //Return null if date format can't be converted
    return null; 
  }

  /**
   * Convert a string value to a date object
   * @param format The format to use in reference to the source 
   * @param source the source to convert
   * @return Date object if the conversion was success; null otherwise
   */
  private static Date formatDate(String format, String source) {
    try {
      return new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(source);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Convert a string value to a date object using SimpleDateFormats 
   * built in styles
   * @param style The style to use
   * @param source the source to convert
   * @return Date object if the conversion was success; null otherwise
   */
  private static Date formatDate(Integer style, String source) {
    try {
      return SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(style).parse(source);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then to use it in your Entity you simple do

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=DateTimeStampDeserializer.class)
@Column(name = "born")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date born;
```

The Jackson libraries can be added to your project via maven (if using maven)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```